# jQuery getting data attribute not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script that produces a number of buttons with a class and I want it to alert the data attribute on click but it's not working.

Here is the output of HTML

```
<button class="request box-button" data-value="18492500814">Request</button>
```

jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.request').each(function () {
        var photoID = $(this);
        photoID.click(function () {
            alert($(this).data('value'));
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: it seems to work pretty fine, see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2s3ngvd3/ what jquery version you are using? Is there anything else which might be affecting your problem? what's the error message you get? *edit* ah nvm, overseen the fact that you are using a script to create the buttons themselves. see blex' answer, then :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your elements don't exist when the page loads, the event won't be bound to them. Fix that by using **event delegation**:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.request', function () {
            alert($(this).data('value'));
    });
});
```

[**JS Fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mc9m37tp/) with dynamically generated elements

*Note: Here, I used `$(document).on()` because I don't have your page's structure. But if you insert the buttons in a container that already exists in your HTML, use this instead: `$('#myContainer').on()`. It won't be noticeable, but it is best for performance.*

Comment: Ahh you gentlemen! I knew it was something to do with this because when I click "view source" there are no relevant elements. So, essentially what you've done with the above is scan the document a second time when using the click event? (poorly explained!)

Comment: @WebDevDanno Well, not really. What it says is: _"When there is a click on **any** element of the document, **if** it corresponds to the selector `'.request'`, then, execute this function."_ That way, even if elements are added later, they will be ckecked and used.

Comment: I see! Thank you, jQuery logic is something I'm currently struggling with. I'm glad there's nice folk out there who can help out! =]

Comment: I like your exemplary sportsmanship. I wish there was more users like you

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have the listener on request, instead of inside of the loop. Also use the `attr` to get the data-value

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.request').click(function () {
        alert($(this).attr('data-value'));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="request box-button" data-value="18492500814">Request</button>
```

Comment: jQuery has a handy tool to obtain values from data- attributes. So it is actually cuter to use the 'data' function. You are right about removing the loop though!

Answer (score 0):

Try with `attr` method.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.request').each(function () {
        var photoID = $(this);
        photoID.click(function () {
            alert($(this).attr('data-value'));
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="request box-button" data-value="18492500814">Request</button>
```